# Spring websocket STOMP Unsubscribe from eventHandler

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a Spring Websocket Stomp application that accepts SUBSCRIBE requests.

In application I have a handler for SUBSCRIBE, that is,

```
 @Component
 public class SubscribeStompEventHandler implements ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {}
 }
```

that I use to validate subscription.

In case if subscription is invalid, for instance, current user can not see that subscription, I would like Broker (I use SimpleMessagingBroker) to "forget" that subscription, or preferably, do not register it at all.

My questions are:

- Can I make Broker to not register the subscription, if I move handling of subscription request to incoming message interceptor and stop message propagation?
- What else could be used from this event handler to cancel the subscription?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554230/how-to-reject-topic-subscription-based-on-user-rights-with-spring-websocket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create you `ChannelInterceptor` implementation. Just extend `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` and override `preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel)`. Here you will get access to headers with session information for validation. Also you need to registrate your interceptor

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.configureBrokerChannel().interceptors(new YourInterceptor())
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

More information here [How to reject topic subscription based on user rights with Spring-websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554230/how-to-reject-topic-subscription-based-on-user-rights-with-spring-websocket)

Comment: Looks good. Do you know if i return null from preSend and do not throw, it will be the same effect?

Comment: You can look on `AbstractMessageChannel.ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend` method. It just sets flag to false if there is no message comes from interceptor. You better try it because I don't know what will happen.@AskarIbragimov